# How to add user locked folders in a SSH server

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ftp, sftp

I am running my SSH server on a Debian build of Linux. When I connect to the server, I get access to the whole laptop's files. when I log int the file location I get access to is: '/home/myuser', but I want to change it so, when you log in to the server, I want there to be multiple users and each user has their own folder they can access and edit. An example of the server's folder would be: '/home/myuser/serverfolder' and within '/home/myuser/serverfolder' there would be a folder for each user.

How can I do what I explained above?

Comment: can you also add who will serve chroot dir? it is local or served from other central server with central server details.

Comment: it's on a local server, but I'm accessing the server by typing in the IP address of the server/computer

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file add this:

```
Match user myuser
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ChrootDirectory /home/myuser/serverfolder
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Note that you also have change this:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

to this

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

in the same `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

And don't forget to restart ssh, after the changes are made: `sudo service ssh restart`

You should also make sure that the user owns the directory you want them to be able to access, but not parent directory:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/myuser/
sudo chown myuser:myuser /home/myuser/serverfolder -R
```

Comment: I've done all of that and nothing has changed when I access the server. Help?

Comment: I though you are connecting with sftp. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Using SFTP on port 22

Comment: Then this should work. Unless u connect via ssh..